# Find duplicate objects based on a property and combine the values of the property

Tags: c#, list, linq, duplicates

I have the following list of objects:

```
[
    {
        "category": "animal",    
        "example": "cat"
    },
    {
        "category": "bird",
        "example": "parrot"
    },
    {
        "category": "animal",
        "example": "dog"
    }
]
```

I need to find out the duplicates and output the following list:

```
[
    {
        "category": "animal",    
        "example": ["cat", "dog"]
    },
    {
        "category": "bird",
        "example": "parrot"
    }
]
```

With the following code, I'm able to find out the duplicates:

```
var a = inputList.GroupBy(x => x.category);
var duplicates = a.Where(item => item.Count() > 1);
```

How do I update the value of example in the inputList?

Comment: Create new objects in the format you want. You've grouped the input so you can loop through each grouped item to access the individual objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how your models looks like but if it looks something like this:

```
public class AnimalsWithExample
{
    public AnimalsWithExample(string category, string example)
    {
        Category = category;
        Example = example;
    }
    
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Example { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalsGrouped
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string[] Examples { get; set; }
}
```

then you can simply do this:

```
var list = new List<AnimalsWithExample>
{
    new AnimalsWithExample("animal", "cat"),
    new AnimalsWithExample("bird", "parrot"),
    new AnimalsWithExample("animal", "dog")
};

var listGrouped = list.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .Select(x => new AnimalsGrouped() { Category = x.Key, Examples = x.Select(y => y.Example).Distinct().ToArray() }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If AnimalsWithExample class has string[] for Example, what would be the code change?

Comment: Then it would be simple as that:

`var listGrouped = list.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => y.Example)).ToList();`
But keep in mind that Example[] may contain duplicates. Only Categories will be unique. If you would like to Examples be unique as well the query will be more complicated.

Comment: Could you please let me know how that query will be?

Comment: Actually disregard my prev comment and just do this:
`var listGrouped = list.GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(x => new AnimalsWithExamples(x.Key, x.SelectMany(x => x.Example).Distinct().ToArray())).ToList();`

Comment: Can you please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73901892/find-duplicate-objects-based-on-a-property-and-combine-the-values-of-the-propert kind of similar to this question

Answer (score 1):

Common type for `string` and `IEnumerable<string>` is `object`, if you are OK with that (e.g. only JSON is needed), you can use that:

```
inputList.GroupBy(x => x.category).Select(grp => new 
{
   category = grp.Key,
   examples = grp.Select(i => i.example).Distinct().ToList()
})
.Select(i => new 
{
  i.category,
  example = i.examples.Count == 1 ? (object)i.examples.First() : i.examples
})
```

Comment: Can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73901892/find-duplicate-objects-based-on-a-property-and-combine-the-values-of-the-propert