# Find common objects based on a property and combine the values of the property into a list

Tags: list, linq, duplicates

I have the following n lists of objects:

```json
{    
    "Pets": [
        {
            "example": "cat",
            "category": "group1"  
            
        },
        {
            "example": "dog",
            "category": "group1"
            
        },
        {
            "example": "cow",
            "category": "group1"
            
        }
    ],
    "exclude": false
}
```

```json
{    
    "Pets": [
        {
            "example": "crow",
            "category": "group2"            
        },
        {            
            "example": "cat",
            "category": "group2"
        },
    ],
    "exclude": true
}
```

```json
{    
    "Pets": [
        {              
            "example": "cow",
            "category": "group3" 
        }
    ],
    "exclude": false
}
```

After finding duplicates, I output the following list:

OUTPUT1:

```json
[
    {
        "example": "cat",
        "categories": ["group1", "group2"]    
       
    },
    {
        "example": "dog",
        "categories": ["group1"] 
    },
    {
        "example": "cow",
        "categories": ["group1", "group3"]    
       
    },
    {
        "example": "crow",
        "categories": ["group2"] 
    }
]
```

with the below code part 1:

```cs
public class AnimalsGrouped
{
    public string Example { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }
}

var pets = input.SelectMany(x => x.Pets).ToList(); //input has the 3 lists mentioned above
var listGrouped = pets.GroupBy(x => x.Example)
   .Select(x => new AnimalsGrouped() 
    { 
        Example = x.Key, 
        Categories = x.Select(y => y.Category).Distinct().ToList() 
    })
    .ToList();
```

I have a key "exclude" in these lists. If exclude is true, remove all those pets from the output list. If exclude is false, add all those pets to the output list.

This is my code part 2:

```cs
var toInclude = input.Where(g => !g.exclude).SelectMany(x => x.Pets).ToList();
var toExclude = input.Where(g => g.exclude).SelectMany(x => x.Pets).ToList();
var diff = toInclude.Except(toExclude).ToList();
```

On running this,

I see this:

OUTPUT2:

```json
[
    {
        "example": "dog",
        "categories": ["group1"] 
    },
        "example": "cow",
        "categories": ["group1"]    //either group1 or group3
       
    }
]
```

How do I compare result from OUTPUT1 & OUTPUT2 and find common objects and output the final list?

The final output should be:

```json
[
    {
        "example": "dog",
        "categories": ["group1"] 
    },
        "example": "cow",
        "categories": ["group1", "group3"]    
       
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Except()` need to compare instances of Pets. In your case two Pets should be equal only if both `example` and `category` are the same, you need custom comparer for that:

```
public class PetComparer: IEqualityComparer<Pet> {
  public GetHashCode(Pet p) => p.Example.GetHashCode() ^ p.Category.GetHashCode();

  public bool Equals(Pet p1, Pet p2) => p1.Example == p2.Example && p2.Category == p2.Category;
}
```

Then use comparer:

```
var diff = toInclude.Except(toExclude, new PetComparer()).ToList();
```